# SQLite - ORDER BY strftime not working but ORDER BY Date is

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union-all, strftime

I have two tables that I'm combining using UNION ALL. I then want to order the resulting table by Date. The original tables are in a DD/MM/YY format as opposed to [YYYY-MM-DD expected by SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). Here's a representative example of what I have.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (Name TEXT, Date TEXT);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
('Washington', '04-06-2017'),
('Pittsburgh', '30-06-2017');

CREATE TABLE T2 (Name TEXT, Date TEXT);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
('Melbourne', '04-06-2017'),
('Sydney', '30-06-2017');

CREATE TABLE T (Name TEXT, Date TEXT);

INSERT INTO T (Name, Date)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Name, Date FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Date FROM T2);
```

When I query these results, if I use:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY Name asc;
```

The sort works. If I use:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY Date
```

The ORDER BY works **but** the order isn't the one I want as SQLite sorts assuming a YYYY-MM-DD format. So I tried to use strftime. However, when I use:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY strftime('%d-%m-%Y', Date) asc;
```

The resulting table is sorted by day (as if the format was as before) **and** the sort is only within the individual parts of the table (i.e., the part above the UNION command and the part below the UNION command). Can anyone explain why this is happening or suggest a resolution to my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so `strftime()` returns NULL.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll convert the date format earlier in the sequence

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column from the Date column that is in a sortable format i.e YYYYMMDD using the `substr` function e.g. :-

```
SELECT *, 
    substr(Date,7,4)||substr(Date,4,2)||substr(Date,1,2) AS sortabledate
    FROM T 
    ORDER BY sortabledate ASC
```